# Google API: Can I authenticate a specific user with PHP Client?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

Users in my app are connecting their Gmail accounts. I have a feature that allows them to disconnect and then before totally deleting the integration and all the data associated with it they can reconnect. I'm using OAuth 2 authentication method.

Currently, when I authenticating back with Google the sign-in screen is presented and if that user has multiple Gmail logins then they are all presented to the user to choose from.

If the user chooses a different email than they chose before this creates a conflict in my system. For this specific scenario, I need to choose that email for them. Is this possible?

Comment: Im not 100% sure i understand what you are asking here.  You could add a login_hint to your authorization request this will ensure that they authenticate the next time with the correct email address.

Comment: Yes! That is much better than what I have right now. Is there a way to skip the "Choose an Account" screen altogether?

Comment: I just posted an answer for you give it a shot.

Comment: NO i dont think there is anyway to skip it unless the user is actually logged in on that account already.   As someone with three google accounts yes its annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to 100% ensure that they will login with the same email address however you can add

```
    $client->setLoginHint('[Users email here]');
```

This will encourage them to login with that email as the popup window where they have to select a google account will only display that one.  This will require that you have saved the email from the last time.

```
function buildClient(){

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access.  Will result in a refresh token
    $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
    $client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
    $client->addScope([YOUR SCOPES HERE]);
    $client->setLoginHint('[Users email here]');
    $client->setRedirectUri(getRedirectUri());  
    return $client;
}
```

## Extra info from the docs

[openidconnect documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters)

[image]

Comment: This is very much in line with what I need. That's unfortunate there isn't a way to bypass the sign-in screen entirely, but this should most definitely help with conflicts.

Comment: You should add this here. If you don't, I might :)  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth

Comment: go for it but there are quite a few of the little used fields that are not actually documented on the libraries.